# Nested IF statements within a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

My source data looks like this:

[image: Data]

I am trying to run the IF statement to categorize based on CPU & Memory sizes using this statement:

```
=
IF(RVOutput[[#Headers],[CPUs]]<2,"S",
IF(RVOutput[[#Headers],[CPUs]]<4,"M",
IF(RVOutput[[#Headers],[CPUs]]<8,"L",
IF(RVOutput[[#Headers],[CPUs]]<16,"XL",
"XXL"))))
```

However, for some reason, the output always ends up being XXL. It almost seems to be skipping the first 4 options.

Comment: Hmm `IF(RVOutput[[#Headers],[CPUs]]<16,"XL" is always true ...

Comment: Where are you putting the formula? Is it going into a column within the RVOutput table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the header (`[[#Headers],[CPUs]]`). This basically means that you are comparing the (string) value `CPUs` to your numerical values, which is always false.

Now, to solve the issues, it depends a bit on where you want your information to be. If you want to put the formula into a cell **outside** of your `RVOutput` table and you want to check for the maximum number of CPUs in the whole column, then you could use:

`IF(MAX(RVOutput[CPUs])<2,"S",...)`

Here `MAX` returns the maximum value of the whole `CPUs` column from the `RVOutput`. You could of course also use `MIN` if that is more interesting to you. Afterwards, that value is compared to your numerical value `2` in the `IF` statement.

[image]

If you want to have the CPU category sizes (S, M, etc.) within the same table for each row, you will have to use:

`=IF([@CPUs]<2, "S", ...)`

The `[@CPUs]` references the value in the `CPUs` column of the same row. So, if you implement this formula in a new column of your `RVOutputs` table, in row 5, then it will look into the row 5 of the `CPUs` column (which is `2`).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That was amazing. I have a follow up question now. I can ask it in a different thread if that is what is the right thing to do. The question is, I have two columns, one for the CPU sizes, and one for Memory sizes. I want to now create a 3rd columns, which has the value that is larger. e.g. If the CPU column has an S, and the Memory column has an L, this 3rd column, should have an L, and so on and so forth. Basically the sizes are S(mall), M(edium), L(arge) and XL(arge). I need to have the largest size in the 3rd column.

Comment: @testcase if the answer was the solution to your (initial) problem, please make sure to mark it as the correct answer. As for your new question: since you are now comparing non-numerical items, you might have to work with some sort of lookup table to check the characters against corresponding values. This will be a completely different topic which doesn't have to do with nested IF statements anymore and therefore a new question is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you Loeli. I did end up solving my other problem by using a 3rd column, which simply compared the first two columns that provided me the highest value. And then I used an IF statement against that value to get me the final answer I needed. Thank you all for you help!